# how to know how many pages a particular user visited in a particular session

Tags: php, mysql, session, url

i am working on a e-commerce website, i want to monitor how many pages a users visited in a particular session. there are only registered users of the site.
 can any one tell me how to record the URL of the user of a particular session, 
i am using php and mysql

Comment: you could create a session variable, e.g. `$_SESSION['pages']` and on every page add 1 to it? Then, when the user actively logs out or when the session ends, update the database with the session id of that user and the number of pages the visited.

Comment: Instead of doing an INSERT for each page view, you may implement your own session handling, storing sessions in a database. Doing this way, you only need to update your page views table once, when the session is deleted.

Answer (score 2):

At some point in the application you could simply perform:

```
$_SESSION['history'][] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Thus appending the current URI to the session's `history` array. You could get more intuitive, such as checking whether the URI exists already, calculating the time difference between pages for reporting purposes, etc.

Comment: This came in very handy,  Thank you.  `$_SESSION['history'][time()] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one way to do this. Here is one quick walkthrough:

1. Create a table with two fields ('session_id', 'url');
2. Whenever the site loads, read the sessionid using `session_id()`, and use this value to store the url of the page in a table for every pages the people visit.
3. Once a page loads, read the URL, through `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` and then use it the value of `session_id()` and store the records.

After you implement this simple technique. you can see how many people see the pages, using a simple query

```
SELECT count(*) FROM <YOURSESSIONTABLE> GROUP BY `<session_id_field>`
```

<sub>P.S. This is one of the basic example, and should be changed to fit your requirements</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Have a mysql table

```
UserID    SessionID     URI
1         XYZ           /
1         XYZ           /contact
1         ZYX           /contact
```

Each page that loads insert this into the table

```
$query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO visits  (`UserID`, `SessionID`, `Uri`)
  VALUES ($userID, " . session_id() . ", " . mysql_real_escape_string(['REQUEST_URI']) . ")";
```

later you can check a session of a user and count up all the different pages with

```
SELECT COUNT(URI) FROM visits WHERE UserID = $userID GROUP BY SessionID
```

you could also associate a datetime with the session

Answer (score 0):

I made a base class that is inherited by `System.Web.UI.Page` like

```
 public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected virtual void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Note: make base class Page load event Virtual and other pages Page load event override and then call base class Page load event in every page Page load event like

```
base.Page_Load(sender, e);
```

Every page is inherited through this base class like

```
protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.Page_Load(sender, e);
    }
```

I did it like this way,

```
        string pageName = Path.GetFileName(Request.PhysicalPath);
        string serverName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MachineName;
        string sessionId = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
        string ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

then insert these values in your database through SQL or LINQ query...

I inserted through LINQ like

```
VisitorInformation vPanel = new VisitorInformation()
        {
            PageName = Path.GetFileName(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalPath),
            ServerName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MachineName,
            SessionId = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID,
            IPAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress,
            VisitorDate = Convert.ToDateTime(System.DateTime.Now.ToString()),
        };
        new BaseDAL().AddVisitorInfo(vPanel);
```